# Trying to solve a non-linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I go about solving for x(t) in the equation below?

$\dfrac{\dot{x}}{\sqrt{1+\dot{x}^2}}=-\dfrac{t}{\lambda}+ C$

It seems as though it is a nonlinear differential equation and I cant seem to find a method that may suitably solve this equation.

I am told that:

> The solution consists of circles and is obtained by the substitution of $\frac{dx}{dt}= \tan{\psi}$ or through direct integration

I tried doing the $\tan$ substitution but dont know how to follow through on it. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Apologies that was a typo. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the direct integration
$$\dfrac{x'}{\sqrt{1+(x')^2}}=f(t)\implies x'=\pm\frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{1-\big[f(t)\big]^2}}$$
$$x=\pm \int \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{1-\big[f(t)\big]^2}}\,dt+K$$
If $f(t)$ is a linear function of $t$, this not difficult. Say $f(t)=at+b$, make $at+b=y$ to face
$$x=\pm \frac 1a \int \frac{y}{ \sqrt{1-y^2}}\,dy+K=\pm\frac 1a \sqrt{1-y^2}+K$$

Comment: The sign of $x'$ is the same as the sign of $f$, only one sign variant is possible (in real calculus).

Answer (score 1):

First note that for this problem the $\lambda$ is a constant.

Let $\frac{dx}{dt} = \tan(u)$. We can also then get $u = \tan^{-1}(\dot{x})$. Now sub this into the equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\tan(u)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(u)}} = -\frac{t}{\lambda}+ c
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\frac{\tan(u)}{\sec(u)} = -\frac{t}{\lambda} + c
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\sin(u)= -\frac{t}{\lambda} + c
\end{equation}
Using the inverse of $\sin(u)$,
\begin{equation}
u= \sin^{-1}\left(-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c\right)
\end{equation}
Now sub in "$u = \tan^{-1}(\dot{x})$"

\begin{equation}
\tan^{-1}(\dot{x})= \sin^{-1}\left(-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c\right)
\end{equation}
thus we get
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}= \tan\left[\sin^{-1}\left(-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c\right)\right]
\end{equation}
Integrate both sides w.r.t $t$, we get
\begin{equation}
\int dx= \int\tan\left[\sin^{-1}\left(-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c\right)\right]dt
\end{equation}
By drawing out the trigonometry functions in the integrand of the second integral we can understand it a little better. This show that out angle $\alpha = \sin^{-1}\left(-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c\right)$
[image]

We can now see that
\begin{equation}
\tan\left[\sin^{-1}\left(-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c\right)\right] = \tan(\alpha) = \frac{-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c}{\sqrt{1 + \left(-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c\right)^2}}
\end{equation}
Sub this back into the integral:
\begin{equation}
\int dx= \int{\frac{-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c}{\sqrt{1 + \left(-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c\right)^2}}}dt
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
x= \int{\frac{-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c}{\sqrt{1 + \left(-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c\right)^2}}}dt + k
\end{equation}
Now focusing on the integral, make another substitution with $v = -\frac{t}{\lambda} + c$, thus we get
\begin{equation}
\int{\frac{-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c}{\sqrt{1 + \left(-\frac{t}{\lambda} + c\right)^2}}}dt = -\lambda\int{\frac{v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2}}}dv
\end{equation}
To make it easier to solve let make another substitution with $z = 1 - v^2$. This is then easily solved to:
\begin{equation}
-\lambda\int{\frac{v}{\sqrt{1 + v^2}}}dv = \frac{\lambda}{2}\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}}dz = \lambda z^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}
Now we substitute back the variables:
\begin{equation}
\lambda z^{\frac{1}{2}} = \lambda (1-v^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \lambda \left(1-\left(\frac{-t}{\lambda} + c\right)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}
Thus returning to the original problem we get:
\begin{equation} 
x = \lambda \left(1-\left(\frac{-t}{\lambda} + c\right)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} +k
\end{equation}
With manipulation:
\begin{equation} 
\frac{x}{\lambda} - d = \left(1-\left(\frac{-t}{\lambda} + c\right)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}
(where $d =\frac{k}{\lambda}$). Now aquare both sides:
\begin{equation} 
\left(\frac{x}{\lambda} - d\right)^2 = 1-\left(\frac{-t}{\lambda} + c\right)^2
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation} 
\left(\frac{x}{\lambda} - d\right)^2 +\left(\frac{-t}{\lambda} + c\right)^2 = 1
\end{equation}
Finally note that $\left(\frac{-t}{\lambda} + c\right)^2 = \left(-1*(\frac{t}{\lambda} - c)\right)^2 = (-1)^2*\left(\frac{t}{\lambda} - c\right)^2 = \left(\frac{t}{\lambda} - c\right)^2$

Sub this in the equation above we get:
\begin{equation} 
\left(\frac{x}{\lambda} - d\right)^2 +\left(\frac{t}{\lambda} - c\right)^2 = 1
\end{equation}